# How to check if a symmetric positive definite matrix is concave?

Tags: matrices, convex-optimization, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices, non-convex-optimization

There is a simple routine for checking if a matrix is positive definite called the Cholesky decomposition. If the matrix isn't, Cholesky functions instantly return an error saying it is not positive definite.

Is there a similar simple routine for checking if a matrix is concave or convex? trying to avoid the laborious inequality proof-check on paper, as well as visually intersecting a line through the graph of the function.

Matrices I had in mind to check for convexity were the covariance matrix, correlation matrix, and matrices filled with probabilities (histogram-estimated pdf values) of multiple variables along the columns (stochastic matrix I guess is what they're called).

Comment: What is the definition of convexity for matrices?

Comment: If $Q$ is your matrix then the function $x \to x^TQx$ is convex if and only if $Q$ is positive semidefinite, if that's your question.

Comment: You need to better define your function. A convex function must be defined as $f: \mathbb{E}\to (-\infty,\infty]$. Therefore we can talk about convexity of matrix eigenvalues, quadratic form, norms, etc. But a matrix on it's own is not a real-valued function.

Comment: i don't think he said the matrix $Q$ is a function, but that the continuous real vector $x$ is, which when used as a weighted average *on* $Q$ makes the objective function as a whole convex?